# If $A$ and $B$ are two matrices of order $3*3$ and $det(A)= 4$ and $det(B)= 5$ , then the value of $2det(A)-2det(B^{-1})$ is?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ and $B$ are two matrices of order $3*3$ and $det(A)= 4$  and $det(B)= 5$, what is the value of $2det(A) - 2det(B^{-1})$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

If $M$ is an invertible matrix then
$$\det\left(M^{-1}\right)=\frac1{\det M}$$

Comment: umm..? well can you find a relationship between what you wrote and this text in the book I study http://upimage.us/server/php/files/20140511_214134-1.jpg ?

Comment: Notice that $\det M$ is a real so the notation $\frac1{\det M}$ makes sense when $\det M\ne0$. The notation $\frac1 A$ isn't allowed since $A$ isn't a real (or complex).

Comment: OH YES ! I didn't pay more attention for that / THANKS

Comment: You're welcome.